# How do you get an SQLITE database (Mydb.db) to load every time you start the iPhone App?

Tags: ios4

I have an app that access a static SQLITE database when running. A user or application is not allowed to alter or update this database.  However,  I need to add records or change field content to keep up with changing URLs etc.  I use MesaSQLite to update the single table.  But when I re-open the app in Xcode Simulator, none of the changes took effect.  It's as if the app did not reload the updated database.

How can I get a reload to take place?  Keep in mind that I'm still covered in shrink wrap because I'm so new to coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of the SQL part. but I think that you will need to reload the table content after getting the update from the database. If you post some code, I can help you better. Here's how to reload the table:

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

And you will need to update the table with the new data in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an IOS4.2 iPhone app. Here is the code for accessing and displaying the sort results of the database.  The purpose  is to use the database to sort delegates by event and state, then display the results.  The displayed delegates are linked to a website.  Again, the user and the app DO NOT alter the database, it's static.  I use an SQLite editor to make changes and import them back into the databases' single table. I just need the table reloaded when this portion of the code runs.

I'll need to know what code and where to insert it for table reload.

Thanks for your help !!!!!

//

//  delegateList.m

//  foundingFathers

//

//  Created by **__** on 6/23/10.

//  Copyright 2010 **MyCompanyName**. All rights reserved.

//

## import "delegateList.h"

static sqlite3 *database = nil;

@implementation delegateList

@synthesize tableView;

-(void)viewDidLoad

{

```
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

stateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

yearsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

contArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

indArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

confArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

constArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



stateNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

eventNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



[self loadStateData];

[self loadEventData];







// Setup some globals

databaseName = @"mydb.db";



// Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];



// Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function

[self checkAndCreateDatabase];



// Query the database for all delegates

[self loadDataWithState:@"" andEvent:0];
```

}

-(void)loadStateData

{

```
[stateNameArray addObject:@"All States"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Connecticut"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Delaware"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Georgia"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Maryland"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Massachusetts"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"New Hampshire"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"New Jersey"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"New York"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"North Carolina"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Pennsylvania"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Rhode Island"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"South Carolina"];

[stateNameArray addObject:@"Virginia"];
```

}

-(void)loadEventData

{

```
[eventNameArray addObject:@"All Events"];

[eventNameArray addObject:@"Continental Association"];

[eventNameArray addObject:@"Declaration of Independence"];

[eventNameArray addObject:@"Confederation of States"];

[eventNameArray addObject:@"US Constitution"];
```

}

-(IBAction)nextPressed:(id)sender

{

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nondelegateList animated:YES];
```

}

-(IBAction)menuPressed:(id)sender

{

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:mainmenu animated:YES];
```

}

/*

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

{

```
switch (interfaceOrientation) {

    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:

    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

        return NO;

        break;

    default:

        return YES;

        break;

}
```

}*/

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  return [nameArray count]+1;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

MyIdentifier = @"tblViewCell";

TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCellView" owner:self options:nil];

    cell = tblCell;

}



UILabel* lbl;

if (indexPath.row == 0) //table Headers

{



    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];



    lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

    lbl.text = @"Name";

    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];



    lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    [lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

    lbl.text = @"State";

    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];



} else {

    //[lbl setFont:[[lbl font] fontWithSize:9]];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];





    lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    lbl.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];



    lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    lbl.text = [stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];



}       



return cell;
```

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    return;

}

NSURL* page = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1] ];

NSURLRequest* pageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:page];

[webTitle setTitle:[nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1]];

[web loadRequest:pageRequest];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
```

}

-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{

```
BOOL success;



NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];



success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];



if(success) return;



NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];



[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];



//[fileManager release];
```

}

-(void)loadDataWithState:(NSString*)stateSearch andEvent:(int)eventSearch

{

```
BOOL hasEvent = (BOOL)eventSearch;

BOOL hasState = !([stateSearch isEqualToString:@"All States"] || stateSearch.length <=0);

NSString* state = stateSearch;

NSString* event = nil;

switch (eventSearch) {

    case 1:

        event = @"continental";

        break;

    case 2:

        event = @"declaration";

        break;

    case 3:

        event = @"confederation";

        break;

    case 4:

        event = @"constitution";

        break;

    default:

        break;

}









// Open the database from the users filessytem





if(database || sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access

    NSString* sqlString = nil;

    const char *sqlStatement;

    if (hasEvent && hasState) {

        sqlString = [[[[@"select * from founding_fathers where "stringByAppendingString:event] stringByAppendingString:@" like 'X%%' and State like '"] stringByAppendingString:state] stringByAppendingString:@"'"];

    }

    if (hasEvent && !hasState) {

        sqlString = [[@"select * from founding_fathers where "  stringByAppendingString:event] stringByAppendingString:@" like 'X%%'"];

    }

    if (!hasEvent && hasState) {

        sqlString = [[@"select * from founding_fathers where state = '" stringByAppendingString:state] stringByAppendingString:@"'"];



    }

    if (!hasEvent && !hasState) {

        sqlString= @"select * from founding_fathers";

    }



    unsigned int lengthOfMessage = [sqlString length];

    char temp[lengthOfMessage + 1];

    strcpy(temp, [sqlString cString]);

    sqlStatement = temp;





    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array

        [nameArray removeAllObjects];

        [stateArray removeAllObjects];

        [yearsArray removeAllObjects];

        [contArray removeAllObjects];

        [indArray removeAllObjects];

        [confArray removeAllObjects];

        [constArray removeAllObjects];

        [urlArray removeAllObjects];



        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            // Read the data from the result row

            NSString* dName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

            NSString* dState = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

            NSString* dYears = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

            NSString* dCont = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

            NSString* dInd = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];

            NSString* dConf = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];

            NSString* dConst = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)];

            NSString* dUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 8)];





            [nameArray addObject:dName];

            [stateArray addObject:dState];

            [yearsArray addObject:dYears];

            [contArray addObject:dCont];

            [indArray addObject:dInd];

            [confArray addObject:dConf];

            [constArray addObject:dConst];

            [urlArray addObject:dUrl];



        }

    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);



}
```

}

-(void)viewDidUnload

{

```
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

-(IBAction)stateSearch:(id)sender

{

```
pickerArray = stateNameArray;

[picker reloadAllComponents];

[picker setHidden:NO];

[doneButton setHidden:NO];
```

}

-(IBAction)eventSearch:(id)sender

{

```
pickerArray = eventNameArray;

[picker reloadAllComponents];

[picker setHidden:NO];

[doneButton setHidden:NO];
```

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

```
return [pickerArray count];
```

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

{

```
return 1;
```

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

```
return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

}

- (void) doneClicked:(id)sender

{

```
if (pickerArray == stateNameArray)

{

    stateSearchChoice = [stateNameArray objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

    [stateButton setTitle:stateSearchChoice];

}



if (pickerArray == eventNameArray) {

    eventSearchChoice = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    [eventButton setTitle:[eventNameArray objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

}

[picker setHidden:YES];

[doneButton setHidden:YES];



[self loadDataWithState:stateSearchChoice andEvent:eventSearchChoice];

[tableView reloadData];
```

}

@end